# Facing issue While making dynamic views using Relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-displaymanager

I'm using relative layout for building the views/grid dynamically...

ex: if there is 1 user then,

[[grid with users 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dqsr.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dqsr.png)

if there is 2 user then ,

[[grid with users 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzrNG.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzrNG.png)

if there is 3 user then,

[[grid with user 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzD5L.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzD5L.png)

if there are 4 user then ,
2 above and 2 below

if there are 5 then,
[[grid with user 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESKsr.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESKsr.png)

if there are 6 then.
[[grid with user 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR7ko.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR7ko.png)

my code is ,

```
 private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[] getgrid(int size) {

  int width = Math.max(getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredHeight());
    int height = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredHeight());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[] array =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width / 2, height);
            array[0].width = array[1].width;
            array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(0)).getId());
            array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
          //  array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        } else if (i == 2) {
            array[i] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width / 3, height);
            array[1].width = array[i].width;
            array[0].width = array[i].width;
            //array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(1)).getId());
        } else if (i == 3) {
            array[i] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width / 2, height / 2);
            array[0].width = array[i].width;
            array[1].width = array[i].width;
            array[i - 1].width = array[i].width;
            array[0].height = array[i].height;
            array[1].height = array[i].height;
            array[i - 1].height = array[i].height;
            array[i - 1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
            array[i - 1].addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(0)).getId());
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(1)).getId());
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(i - 1)).getId());
        } else if (i == 4) {
            array[i] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width / 3, height / 2);
            array[0].width = array[i].width;
            array[1].width = array[i].width;
            array[2].width = array[i].width;
            array[3].width = array[i].width;
            array[0].setMargins(width / 6, 0, 0, 0);
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(i - 1)).getId());
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        } else if (i == 5) {
            array[i] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width / 3, height / 2);
            array[0].setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(1)).getId());
            array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        }
    }

     return array;
}
```

the issue is there is another view right besides the relative layout so basically its not getting equally divided and distorted as well (distorted means some grid is not covering the full height)

please refer this:--
[[issue with 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3IFS.png)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3IFS.png)

[[issue with 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeUhq.png)][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeUhq.png)
and so on

please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: int width = Math.max(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
int height = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[] array = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          array[i] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0, height);
          array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            if (i > 0) {
                array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(i - 1)).getId());
        }
       array[i].width = width / size;
     }
 return array; }

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli this is for which case ?? user with 3 or 4 ? did u see my six screenshot that is my target

Comment: for all case try this and check if it is working correctly?

Comment: I don't have getMeasuredWidth() to test this..

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli i tried this ...every user is getting added one after another..
thats not what i want

Comment: that is also not equally aligned please refer issue screenshot

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli can suggest some more solution for above issue

Comment: @IRONMAN Do we have max limit to add child views? It feels like ordinary grid/staggering arrangements won’t work dynamically. Just wanted to understand about the max limit so that I can provide some suggestions.

Comment: max limit is 6 @JeelVankhede...i need to use relative layout only for dynamic cells

Answer (score 1):

[image]To make Dynamic view as you see it, I wrote the following code:

Note: There is an exception for the 5 view because it needs to be wrapped inside another view (in my case, the linear layout).

Currently, the width and height of the relative layout are fixed as follows:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
```

whole activity code:

```
    public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    List<UserView> mUserViewList;
    List<Integer> mUidList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

         relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);



        mUserViewList = new ArrayList<>();
        mUidList = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = 5;


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[] array = getgrid2(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            //createing user view and addding in view list
            UserView userView = new UserView(this);
            mUserViewList.add(userView);

            //setting id and addint to id list
            userView.setId(i);
            mUidList.add(i);

            //settting text to user view
            userView.setTextView("User " + (i+1));

            if (array[i]==null)
                continue;
            //setting layout
            mUserViewList.get(i).setLayoutParams(array[i]);
            //adding to views
            if (i==4){

                relativeLayout.addView(exptionalMethodFor5view());
            }
            relativeLayout.addView(mUserViewList.get(i));
        }
    }


    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[] getgrid2(int size) {

//        int width = Math.max(relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth(),relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
//        int height = Math.min(relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth(),relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

         int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
         int height =dpToPx(200);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[] array =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams[size];
        switch (size){
            case 1: {
                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;

            }
            case 3: {
                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[2] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        height/2 );
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        height/2);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[2] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        height/2);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[3] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        height/2);
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
//                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
//                        width/3,
//                        height/2 );
//                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
//                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

//                array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
//                        width/3,
//                        height/2);
                //top right
//                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
//                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[2] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[3] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


                array[4] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[4].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[4].addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2 );
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[2] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[3] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[4] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[4].addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[5] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/3,
                        height/2);
                array[5].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[5].addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;
            }

            default:{
                array[0] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                array[1] = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        width/2,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                break;
            }
        }
        return array;



    }

    private LinearLayout exptionalMethodFor5view(){
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        UserView newUserview1 = new UserView(this);
        newUserview1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels)/3,
                dpToPx(200)/2));

        UserView newUserview2 = new UserView(this);
        newUserview2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels)/3,
                dpToPx(200)/2));

        linearLayout.addView(newUserview1);
        linearLayout.addView(newUserview2);
        return linearLayout;
    }


    public static int dpToPx(float dp) {
        float density = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round(dp * density);
    }
}
```